# Cannot connect to proxy error requests.get (python)

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to connect to a proxy with requests.get, and whenever I try, I get a cannot connect to proxy error. Here is my code:

```py
import requests

proxies = {
 "http": "181.113.68.196:8080",
 "https": "181.113.68.196:8080",
}
r = requests.get("https://thewebsite.com", proxies=proxies)
```

That ouputs this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='thewebsite.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /python-requests-proxy (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))
```

Im just putting thewebsite.com because it does the same thing with all of the websites I input. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you double check whether the proxy URL is actually correct and working?

Comment: How do you do that? My friend that codes gave me a list of proxies but im not sure if they work now.

Comment: many free proxy servers doesn't work. If you get this error then it may means that this proxy doesn't work and you have to use different.

Comment: Do you know any that do work? im trying a bunch that im finding and they all say http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Comment: wait I found one! Thanks!

Comment: there are portals like https://sslproxies.org/ which give free proxies but they may not work.